# deeplink assetlinks verifies one server but not other for android app

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have an Android app that can talks to staging server and production server based on debug/release build.
These builds can be signed by any of 3 different keys (custom debug, upload key or play store signing key).

To handle this case I added following file to be served on `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` from both servers (staging and production). I tried pulling it using chrome and postman with content-type = application/json.

```json
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "<package_id>",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["<hashOfKey1>"]
  }
},
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "<package_id>",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["<hashOfKey2>"]
  }
},
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "<package_id>",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["<hashOfKey3>"]
  }
}
]
```

Also, host in data of intent-filter is specified using manifestPlaceholders (which seems to be working fine) like this:

```xml
                   <data
                    android:host="${hostName}"
                    android:path="/dashboard/profile/private"
                    android:scheme="https"
                    />
```

**Problem**
When I build debug (which talks to staging server) app, app is handling staging urls just fine. But when I build release app (I tried by signing custom debug key and upload key), app does not handle production urls.

I can't figure out what it would not work for production links.

Answer (score 0):

After looking for way to find exact problem, I found standard tool.
https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://<domain_as_per_manifest>&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

Problem was I specified `example.com` and internally assetlinks.json request was redirected and served by `www.example.com` (which I did not know). When I used the mentioned tool, it showed me that redirects were not allowed.